# When pressing the any Button on Asp.net form Default Button is also pressed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have an ASP.net form  with buttons on it.

When I try to press any button, the button which is set as default is also pressed.

And this only happens when I use Firefox browser. Does not happen on Internet Explorer.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: could you provide the markup please?

Comment: You could try returning false...

Comment: Aamir Abro can u give me the example ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this issues is solved by removing the lable tags from above and down to the buttons.

Thanks all in contributing my answer.

The World is Gold if U r Bold.